# Is there a way to display the form field as mm/yyyy in html form?

Tags: html, forms, html-formhandler

I'm trying to have a form field with mm/yyyy as an input. Can you help me in suggesting a way to have this date format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html code use the input element and give it the "month" type (YYYY-MM)

```
<input type="month" id="something" />
```

To get the date and year, you can use javascript

```
var date = document.getElementById("something").value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the below code in your form. It should allow you to enter the month first then the year after.

```
<label for="start">Date:</label>
<input type="month" id="start">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to see.

```
<p id="time"></p>

<script>

    const now = new Date();
    const year = now.getFullYear();
    let month = now.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10) 
        month = '0' + month;
    const time = month + '/' + year;
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = time;

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern for your html input field like this:

```
<form>
<input type="text" pattern="[0-1]{1}[0-9]{1}/[0-9]{4}">
</form>
```

It will not accept anything unless it matches "MM/YYYY" pattern.

Answer (score -1):

`<label for="birthdayMonth">Enter Birthday month-year:</label> <input type="month" id="birthdayMonth" name="birthdayMonth">`
Try this:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).